# Accessing other user calendar using service account

Tags: c#, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

We are trying to integrate office 365 using EWS managed API's. We have created one service account with impersonation role using office 365 admin center. 
Now, how can we use that service account to access other user's data(like mails, contacts, calendar) in the application ?
Thanks, Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an instance of ExchangeService as usual and then set its ImpersonatedUserId.

Sample:

```
var credentials = new WebCredentials(
    "impersonateduser@your.onmicrosoft.com", "password", "");

var exchange = new ExchangeService{PreAuthenticate=true, Credentials=credentials};
exchange.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(
    ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, 
    "calendaruser@your.onmicrosoft.com");
```

After this you can access the other user's (in this case `calendaruser`) data.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just another query, Can we use impersonated userID with OAuth to generate clientID,access token etc ?

Comment: it is giving me error as 'The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it' for the calendar user ?? Why this error is coming ??

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx and all of its sub-topics is a good place to start.