# Add Appointment/meeting to a user Outlook Calendar- from ASP.NET MVC Webapplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'am programming a MVC booking-application for an insurance company with 4 sales-consultants.

With this bookingApplication, people can book a appointment/meeting with one of those 4 consultants directly in their Outlook calendars.

if I have those 4 consultants outlook-login-credentials (username and password), then i ezaly can add an appointment/meeting to a sales consultant calender like this.

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1@contoso.com", "password");
    service.Url = new Uri(Settings.ExchangeServer);

var appointment = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = setAppointmentDto.Title;
appointment.Body = setAppointmentDto.Message;
appointment.Location = setAppointmentDto.Location;

 ...

appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

I cant use line below, if i not have those consulents password.

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials ( "user1@contoso.com", "password");
```

Can I Authenticating consultants in a different way (how)?

**Oauth2 client credentials flow (I dont know what is is...and how to use it ) ?**

All four sales consultants are already created in Microsoft CRM and Windows. It may be possible via (Active Directory ... i dont know.

Comment: Hi, did you already read something about [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ?

Comment: Hi Kooki : 
I think Impersonation is what i need. I have read about impersonation, but it real confussing me.
Is it correctly understood that the company "Exchange Administrator" must "defined a group of users" , that my application that can work on ?.

I can then in my code create an apointment on a user's Outlook calendar, by first enter the user's email address like this in the code:
exchangeServiceInstance.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId (ConnectingIdType.SMTP, "xx@cxx.com");

The users email exist in "define a group of users on Exchange Server" ?

Comment: when we are using  Impersonation, should the WebCredentials bee of our appication "service account" in Exchange Server ?  

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("service account email address", "password");

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that using **Impersonation**. This way you don't need to have the consultants' passwords. You will only need the impersonation account email and password.

Use this link to learn more about [Impersonation Configuration](http://support.xink.io/support/solutions/articles/1000157751-how-to-assign-application-impersonation-in-admin-center-office-365-) and [More on Impersonation Configuration](https://cloudsolutions.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CKB/pages/4358166/Setting+up+Application+Impersonation+for+Exchange+or+Office+365).

Once you have created the user and the role, and set the configuration to allow impersonation, you can go ahead and write the code.

You instantiate the service and set the credentials like this:

```
WebCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(
            "impersonate@domain.com", "YourPassword", "");

exchangeService = new ExchangeService { PreAuthenticate = true, Credentials = 
 credentials };

exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(
            ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress,
            "consultant1@domain.com");
```

I found the above code on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27620731/1984709).

After you have instantiated the service with the correct credentials, you can go ahead and create Appointments. Your current code should work:

```
var appointment = new 
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = setAppointmentDto.Title;
appointment.Body = setAppointmentDto.Message;
appointment.Location = setAppointmentDto.Location;
...
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

As it will create an appointment and the Organizer will be "consultant1@domain.com". It will also add it to the consultant's calendar.

You can use Impersonation for much more, such as sending an email on behalf of a specific user, see all appointments for that user, etc.

One important thing to keep in mind is the **"Security considerations for impersonation"**. According to [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_0):

> Impersonation enables a caller to impersonate a given user account. This enables the caller to perform operations by using the permissions that are associated with the impersonated account, instead of the permissions that are associated with the caller's account. For this reason, you should be aware of the following security considerations:
>
> - Only accounts that have been granted the ApplicationImpersonation role by an Exchange server administrator can use impersonation.
> - You should create a management scope that limits impersonation to a specified group of accounts. If you do not create a management scope, the ApplicationImpersonation role is granted to all accounts in an organization.
> - Typically, the ApplicationImpersonation role is granted to a service account dedicated to a particular application or group of applications, rather than a user account. You can create as many or as few service accounts as you need.

So you have to make sure you address those considerations.

I hope this helps.

Here are other useful links:

- [How to: Send email messages by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [How to: Get appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [How to: Create appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495611(v=exchg.150).aspx)